# How to pass a method from exception class into exception constructor?

Tags: java, exception, error-handling

I have written a class which is supposed to model a car and the fuel system, once the car drives past a certain distance, I am trying to throw an "OutOfFuelException" and in doing so, I would like to pass a method from the OutOfFuelException class into the constructor call, but I'm not sure how to do that without actually creating an instance of the class.

Here is the code for the exception class:

```
public class OutOfFuelException extends Exception {
    private double fuelNeeded;

    public OutOfFuelException (double fuelNeeded) {
        super("You need fuel!");
        this.fuelNeeded = fuelNeeded;
    }

    public double getShortfall() {
        return fuelNeeded;
    }
}
```

And here is the attempt at using the method call:

```
if (miles > getRange()) {
            fuel = 0;
            throw new OutOfFuelException(getShortfall());
        }
```

Comment: The exception shouldn't really hold state, but rather is solely used to communicate the error where needed. So the fulelNeeded should be passed into the super's constructor so that the stacktrace will display this value. For example: `super("You need fuel: " + fuelNeeded);`

Answer (score 0):

Your `Exception` class might accept a *Functional* interface.

```
public class OutOfFuelException extends Exception {
   public OutOfFuelException(final Supplier<String> valueSupplier) {
      super(valueSupplier.get());
   }  

   ...
}
```

In this case, you can pass to the constructor a method reference which doesn't accept parameters and which return a `String` value, or an appropriate *lambda* expression.

```
public void myMethod() throws OutOfFuelException {
   ...

   if (miles > getRange()) {
      throw new TestException(this::buildValue);
   }
}

public String buildValue() {
    return "My value";
}
```

Adjust for your needs, but please, don't do that.

Comment: Shouldn't `final String value = valueSupplier.get();` instead be `super(valueSupplier.get());`? Without passing the key information into the Exception child class's super constructor, the stacktrace will not contain the key information.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels that's just an example. He/she will adjust it as needed.

Comment: Sorry, but it looks to be a very bad example then

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels OP asked "how do I pass a method"

Comment: It's an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info) type question -- they're new to Java and don't know what they truly want, worded the question poorly, and what they want to do is pass a value.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I'll keep this answer. Someone might want to try it out.

Answer (score 0):

Let's keep this simple: All you need to do is to pass the Exception constructor's double parameter into the super constructor's parameter, that's it.

The exception shouldn't really hold state, but rather is mainly used to communicate the error where needed. So the fulelNeeded should be passed into the super's constructor so that the stacktrace will display this value. For example:

```
super("You need fuel: " + fuelNeeded);
```

the whole thing is simpler than how you're wiring it:

```
public class OutOfFuelException extends Exception {

    public OutOfFuelException (double fuelNeeded) {
        super("Fuel shortfall: " + fuelNeeded);
    }
}
```

So this should work:

```
if (miles > getRange()) {
    fuel = 0;
    throw new OutOfFuelException(getShortfall());
}
```

or perhaps more simply:

```
if (miles > getRange()) {
    fuel = 0;
    throw new OutOfFuelException(miles - getRange());
}
```